# Black screen when creating UITabBarController from xib

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, xib

I try to create `UITabBarController` from xib. So I setup tab items in xib, connect classes and xibs names for controllers like that. [Open image in full resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YH5c4.png).

[image: like that]

Then I set TabBarController as root view controller.

[image: root view controller]

As result, I get a black screen with no tab items.

[image: black screen]

I can create `UITabBarController` programmatically, so the question is: how can I get what I create in xib?

Comment: please post what you already have

Comment: We need to see your code otherwise we may only speculate.

Comment: @JacobKing View Controllers are empty. All I've done is create UI in xib and instantiate TabBarController in AppDelegate.

Comment: @kuzdu I posted screenshots with everything I've done.

Comment: Can you provide the code for your TabBarController initialiser? Just want to make sure you're loading the nib properly as that's a common mistake.

Comment: @JacobKing I don't have any initializers for TabBarController.

Comment: Can you try my answer just as a sanity check please, if that doesn't help then we'll explore other options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a special way in which view controllers within nibs must be loaded, else the class is loaded without any of the backing UI.

Create the following method in `TabBarController`:

```
class func instantiateFromNib() -> TabBarController {
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "TabBarController", bundle: nil)
    let vc = nib.instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as! TabBarController
    return vc
}
```

Now, in your `AppDelegate`, invoke it like so:

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
window?.rootViewController = TabBarController.instantiateFromNib()
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Give this a try.

Comment: Thanks! it helped.

Comment: Ohh! you can't. I did it on behalf you :)